# C# dotnet core PCSC and the OMNIKEY 3121

Tags: c#, smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc, omnikey

I have a working application where a tachograph remotely connects with my software and authenticates with a certified "tachograph company smart card". The application works perfectly with a [VDO card reader](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fleet.vdo.com%2Fproducts%2Fvdo-card-reader%2F&psig=AOvVaw20sHZAqn8Y_b10et97yKux&ust=1619187314005000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCLDy5_eEkvACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD) and for reasons, I'm now trying to let it work with a [HID OMNIKEY 3121](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.nl%2FHID-Omnikey-chipkaartlezer-zwart-grijs%2Fdp%2FB06XY2XLWF&psig=AOvVaw1J2vuy4Nprl1amL3P-tqaz&ust=1619187561778000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCMjt9e-FkvACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD). I use standard c# [library](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp) calls and nothing special. I can connect with the reader and I am able to see that the reader is indeed connected. However, I cannot communicate with the smart card.

As far as I know, these smart cards follow the standard ISO 7816 and if the reader is ISO 7816 compliant, it should work... Right? The reader is compliant I believe. Whenever I try to read some data from the card (by sending a specific set of APDUs to select a DF and read the binary from the card) the red light on the reader flashes and nothing happens. As if the sending of APDUs are not processed correctly. But I'm not really sure what happens.

Does anybody know why I can use a VDO reader, but not an OMNIKEY? Does OMNIKEY require some extra steps on the initialisation or use with PCSC C# or something?

Comment: What has changed since your previous postings?

Comment: Changed what do you mean? that it is working now? The other programmer fixed a bug in the device we connect to the tachograph and now everything works:) But for research purposes, I want to know if I can get it to work with the OMNIKEY instead of the VDO as well. Do you mean that?

Comment: As long as the vendor driver for reader is installed and in both cases the card is unlocked it should work.  Check device manager to make sure the correct driver is installed.  The driver for reader also need to support the address/data size for card.  Cards have been around for a long time.  Earl cards were 8 bit address/data new cards are larger.  So an old reader may not support new cards.  Also new readers may not be backwards compatible with older cards (unlikely).  One reader may be unlocking card and other readaer may not.  It is problably the driver.

Comment: Solved: You are right my good sir. I already downloaded a driver but it apparently was an old one or something. I downloaded this one (for linux x 64): https://www.hidglobal.com/drivers/29738. And everything works now. Thanks man!